# Got error when try to add Media Uploader

Tags: wordpress

I have include the current js file into my theme

```
<script src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory');?>/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory');?>/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
```

When I try to use in my plugin.

```
wp_enqueue_script('media-upload');
wp_enqueue_script('thickbox');
```

I get the current error

```
TypeError: jQuery.easing[jQuery.easing.def] is not a function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to open your jquery easing plugin file and wrap the code inside:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Put all the code inside here
});
```